# Parsing expression with exponents and evaluating

Tags: java, beginner, parsing, math-expression-eval

I'm programming a basic command line calculator in java that can parse expressions and evaluate them, *does not handle brackets yet*.

For example an expression: \$9+9/2^2*5-1\$.

At this point I can give my program an expression that contains exponents, and It will evaluate them one by one until there are none left.

For example, I can input the following string: \$2^2+1\$ and it will output \$4.0+1\$.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String powerExpression = "2^2+1";

        loopPower(powerExpression);
    }

    public static void loopPower(String exp) {
        while (containsExponents(exp)) {
            exp = procPower(exp);
        }

        System.out.println("FINAL ANSWER IS: " + exp);

}
    public static boolean containsExponents(String exp) {
        boolean contains = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < exp.length(); i++) {
            if (exp.charAt(i) == '^') {
                contains = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return contains;
    }

    public static String procPower(String exp) {
        int operandOneStart = 0;
        int operandTwoStart = 0;
        int operandTwoEnd = 0;
        boolean onFirst = true;
        boolean foundOp = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < exp.length(); i++) {
            if (isCharNumerical(exp.charAt(i))) {
                if (onFirst) {
                    operandOneStart = i;
                    onFirst = false;
                }
                if (foundOp) {
                    operandTwoStart = i;
                    //Perform op

                    String operandOne = "";
                    String operandTwo = "";
                    //Get operand1
                    for (int op1 = operandOneStart; op1 < exp.length();op1++) {
                        if (isCharNumerical(exp.charAt(op1))) {
                            operandOne += exp.charAt(op1);
                        }
                        else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    //Get operand2
                    for (int op2 = operandTwoStart; op2 < exp.length(); op2++) {
                        if (isCharNumerical(exp.charAt(op2))) {
                            operandTwo += exp.charAt(op2);
                        }
                        else {
                            operandTwoEnd = (op2-1);
                            System.out.println("Op 2 End: " + operandTwoEnd);
                            break;
                        }

                        if (isCharNumerical(exp.charAt(op2)) & op2 == (exp.length()-1)) {
                            operandTwoEnd = op2;
                            System.out.println("Op 2 End: " + operandTwoEnd);
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println("Operand One: " + operandOne);
                    System.out.println("Operand Two: " + operandTwo);

                    boolean noBeforenoAfter = false;
                    boolean yesBeforeyesAfter = false;
                    boolean noBeforeyesAfter = false;
                    boolean yesBeforenoAfter = false;

                    float opx1 = Float.valueOf(operandOne);
                    float opx2 = Float.valueOf(operandTwo);

                    if (operandOneStart == 0 & operandTwoEnd == (exp.length()-1)) {
                        noBeforenoAfter = true;
                        exp = String.valueOf(Math.pow(opx1, opx2));
                    }

                    if (operandOneStart > 0 & operandTwoEnd < (exp.length()-1)) {
                        yesBeforeyesAfter = true;
                        String before = "";
                        for (int a = 0;a < operandOneStart;a++) {
                            before += exp.charAt(a);
                        }
                        String after = "";
                        for (int a = operandTwoEnd+1; a < exp.length(); a++) {
                            after += exp.charAt(a);
                        }

                        double subans = Math.pow(opx1,opx2);
                        exp = before + String.valueOf(subans) + after;
                    }

                    if (operandOneStart == 0 & operandTwoEnd < (exp.length()-1)) {
                        noBeforeyesAfter = true;
                        String after = "";
                        for (int a = operandTwoEnd+1; a < exp.length(); a++) {
                            after += exp.charAt(a);
                        }
                        double subans = Math.pow(opx1,opx2);
                        exp = String.valueOf(subans) + after;

                    }

                    if (operandOneStart> 0 & operandTwoEnd == (exp.length()-1)) {
                        yesBeforenoAfter = true;
                        String before = "";
                        for (int a = 0;a < operandOneStart;a++) {
                            before += exp.charAt(a);
                        }
                        double subans = Math.pow(opx1,opx2);
                        exp = before+subans;
                    }

                    //
                    break;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (exp.charAt(i) == '^') {
                    foundOp = true;
                }
                else {
                    onFirst = true;
                    foundOp = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return exp;
    }

    public static boolean isCharNumerical(char c) {
        boolean numerical = false;

        switch (c) {
            case '0':
                numerical = true;
                break;
            case '1':
                numerical = true;
                break;
            case '2':
                numerical = true;
                break;
            case '3':
                numerical = true;
                break;
            case '4':
                numerical = true;
                break;
            case '5':
                numerical = true;
                break;
            case '6':
                numerical = true;
                break;
            case '7':
                numerical = true;
                break;
            case '8':
                numerical = true;
                break;
            case '9':
                numerical = true;
                break;
            case '.':
                numerical = true;
                break;
            default:
                numerical = false;
                break;
        }

        return numerical;
    }
}
```

What is the quality of what I have written/coded? Anything I need to change? Should I go on to make my parser be able to do other arithmetic operations such as multiplication, division, adding, subtracting, **or does this need lots of improvement at this stage**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a comment you state that you "was trying to follow PEMDAS", that is Parenthesis, Exponents, Multiply and Divide, Addition and Subtraction, which sounds like a good track to follow. However you would benefit from preprocessing your string into an array or list consisting of two types of elements, and that is numbers and tokens (like `(`, `)`, `^`, `*`, `/`, `+`, `-`).

When this array is created you have a much easier task of walking through the array (or list) and simplify it step by step, going through the PEMDAS. With a proper list, you find your wanted operator, and then pick the number in front and after the operator and calculate it. Replace the three elements you justed calculated, and repeat simplification...

By the way, what I've just described is a simple variant of building an Abstract Syntax Tree (consisting of numbers and tokens), which you then parse into the expression you want to calculate. The great advantage of doing this in these two steps is that you can focus your attention on either picking numbers or tokens, or afterwards actually simplifying/calculating according to PEMDAS.

Sorry, for not providing actual code, but you seem to know enough to understand how to walk through the list once to extend the numbers and tokens. Afterwards, keep manipulating the array (or list), which hopefully also is known operations.

**Added:** I've [asked a question my self](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/114687/78136) here on Code Review, which implements a calculator like the one I've described above (with exception of parentheses) written in Python. Hopefully this could still give you some hints on another approach for making a calculator.

### Addendum: Comments on code logic

In the following I'm going to *ignore* the restructure I've suggested, but try to give some comments on your existing code. This is to help you understand why you've been given comments that your code is a mess, having bad logic, and so on.

- *Choose better and more meaningful names* – The `exp` could be short of both `expression` and `exponentiation`, which is rather confusing when you only do exponentiation in your code. You also intermix exponents and power in `containsExponents` and `loopPower`, which is slightly confusing. I would rather use the full `expression` or possibly `text`, and `containsPowerOperator` and `calculatePowers` for these methods.

  Another example are the `yesBeforenoAfter` & co variables. These are both confusing and unused, and I'll come back to these later on.

  Lastly the `operandOneStart` and `operandTwoEnd`, I think I would rather use `firstOperandStartIdx` and `secondOperandEndIdx` which would clearer convey what they are used for.
- *Extract more into functions* - You could easily separate the entire loop for getting operands into a new function. You could call it like `double firstOperand  = new Operand(expression, firstOperandStartIdx)`, and if bold you let the `firstOperand` be a dedicated class having optional original `text`, `value`, and `startIdx` and `endIdx` parts.
- *Simplify the rebuild of the expression* – Instead of all of the code you've given with the `yesBeforenoAfter` & co, you could make this into a function as well, which simply concatenates the following string parts:

  - The substring from start of string to `firstOperand.startIdx`, or nothing if that is 0
  - The string version of the current result
  - The substring from `secondOperand.endIdx` to end of string, or nothing if that is 0
- *Flag variables and first operand...* – There are some logic related to keeping track of the start of the first operand and whether you've found the operator or not which I'm not entirely sure how it actually works. (And as previously suggested, this would be way simpler if you'd already processed the list into tokens like numbers and operators. :-).

  However I think you might have a bug here, and should test with expressions like `10^3 + 11^2` and see whether they give the expected output or not.  I think I would have replaced the `onFirst` with setting the `firstOperandStartIdx = -1` and testing against that. I would most likely also invert the if-statements so that it's clearer at the top what is happening, see refactored code below.
- ***Feature/bug:** Your code will break on two exponential expression in the same expression* – If I'm not mistaken your code will only accept one exponential expression, as you do a `break` after finding the operator. In my refactored code below, this is not handled either. But you should look into it
- *Why do the `containsExponents` at all?* – The code as it stands runs through the entire expression twice if it has the exponent operator. However you could simplify this by simply calling the `loopPower` (or `calculatePowers`:-) ) method once. The method would then loop the string once, and if nothing is found, it return the original expression. If the operator is found it still has only looped it once, but now it has rebuilt the expression without the exponential part, and are ready for next step.
- *Simplify the `isCharNumerical()`* – As suggested by πάντα ῥεῖ, you could simplify this function quite a bit...

#### Refactored code

I'll provide you with some untested code if you choose to proceed with your implementation and not going the route via tokens. This would need for a new class, `Operand`, something like the following:

```
public class Operand {
    String text;
    double value;
    int startIdx;
    int endIdx;

    public Operand(String text, int startIdx) {
        this.startIdx = startIdx;

        this.text = "";
        for (int idx = startIdx; idx < text.length(); idx++) {
            char currentChar = text.charAt(id);

            if (isCharNumerical(currentChar)) {
                this.text += currentChar;

            } else {
                this.endIx = idx - 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        this.value = Double.valueOf(this.text);
    }
}
```

And then your calculatePowers would look something like the following untested code:

```
public static String calculatePowers(String text) {
    int firstOperandStartIdx = -1;
    boolean foundOperator = false;
    int startNextPart = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char currentCharacter = text.charAt(i);

        if (!isCharNumerical(currentCharacter)) {
           
            foundOperator = (currentCharacter == '^');
            
            // If this was not the operator we're looking for
            // flag that we need to start looking for a new operand
            if (!foundOperator) {
                firstOperandStartIdx = -1;
            }

        } else {
            // If start of operand hasn't been found, set this 
            // index to be start of number
            if (firstOperandStartIdx < 0) {
                firstOperandStartIdx = i;
            } 

            if (foundOperator) {
                Operand firstOperand = new Operand(text, firstOperandStartIdx);
                Operand secondOperand = new Operand(text, i);
                
                String new_expression = text.substring(startNextPart, firstOperand.startIdx);

                new_expression += String.valueOf(Math.pow(firstOperand.value, secondOperand.value);

                new_expression += text.substring(secondOperand.endIdx + 1, text.length());
      
                // This will need a little tweaking, if you want
                // the newly calculated part to be part of the next
                // expression as well... This is merely a start
                // related to fixing the only one exponential expression bug...
                startNextPart = secondOperand.endIdx;
            }
        }
    }

    return new_expression;
}
```

Comment: I have never heard of the word token in this context, and googling it is not helping me, could somebody refer me or explain in their own words: what a token is?

Comment: @penguinguy, you could also use `operator`... Token is simply put, an even more generalized term.

Comment: So "token" means a type of character? For example "Hello World!", would the '!' be a token?

Comment: @penguinguy, Here are some reading describing the wider use of `token`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Token

Comment: Overall, could you say my logic is flawed or my approach needs improvement.

Comment: @penguinguy, your logic is hidden within a lot of extraneous code, so my suggestion is to rebuild doing the parsing of tokens as described. That is to build a list of numbers and operators, and then start working on doing the calculation.  So _I think_ you're on the right track, but you need to simplify and avoid the heavy logic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33260/discussion-between-penguinguy-and-holroy).

Comment: @penguinguy, sorry, I don't have time right now...

Comment: @penguinguy Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Token) for a definition of token. I should say a tokenizer

Answer (score 5):

Just for one thing: The `isCharNumerical()` function doesn't actually need a `switch` statement, it could be simplified just as

```
public static boolean isCharNumerical(char c) {   
    return (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
}
```

Don't overcomplicate boolean conditions, just take them straightforward.

---

In general for your parser, make operator precedence clear at any state of parsing.

What you have in your example clearly states that operator `^` precedes operator `+`, which is the *natural* expectation. Require brackets to group math expressions being processed in different order.

Comment: What are some of the other approaches that I took that could be improved?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Require brackets to group math expressions being processed in different order" ,"different order" specifically.

Comment: @penguinguy Different order by means of evaluating the addition for the exponent before the power function of course.

Comment: I thought your not supposed to evaluate addition before power function?

Comment: @penguinguy That's what's called the _natural_ operator precedence, yes. Implement this in your parser in a generic way.

Comment: Im so confused sorry, could you re-state from the beginning in easier to understand terms what is wrong with the order it handles them in now? Like an example of what would cause it to give a invalid output.

Comment: @penguinguy I'm afraid that's actually not _easy to understand_ stuff. What you really need is to make your parser producing an abstract syntax tree (AST), and evaluating all of the sub expressions by walking through it too get the final result. That's way too broad to be described with an answer here. There are whole books written about that. All I can say is, that your approach is way too naive, sorry.

Comment: Okay, I was trying to follow PEMDAS. I programmed it to evaluate an expression like a human would.

Answer (score 3):

- [Don't assign to parameters.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/245809/170361) See multiple assignments to `exp`
- Use meaningful names. See `loopPower` and `procPower`
- separate logic and IO. See multiple `System.out.println` peppered in.
- Remove dead code. See `noBeforenoAfter`, `yesBeforeyesAfter`, `noBeforeyesAfter`, `yesBeforenoAfter`. [I wonder what were you thinking](http://www.osnews.com/story/19266/WTFs_m).
- Remove duplication. e.g. Numerous occurrences of  `double subans = Math.pow(opx1,opx2);` and `for (...) { operand... += exp.charAt(...);}`
- Don't mix precisions. e.g. `double subans = Math.pow(opx1,opx2);`. Use double and stick with it.
- Avoid long methods.
- Avoid multiple levels of nesting.